# Why does pylint object to protected member on a deepcopy?

Tags: python, pylint

In the following code, pylint is fine with `clone` updating `_generation` but not with it calling `_prime_me`. [Access to protected member _prime_me of a client class (protected-access).]

- Why?
- Is there a way of calling a 'private' method on a copy which does not inflame pylint?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import copy

class DollyTheSheep:

    def __init__(self):
        self._name = "Dolly"
        self._generation = 0

    def _prime_me(self):
        self._name += "'"

    def clone(self):
        next_gen = copy.deepcopy(self)
        next_gen._generation += 1
        next_gen._prime_me()
        return next_gen
```

Comment: Fair enough to regard 'Pythonic' questions as about coding style. I revised the point to focus on pylint.

Answer (score 0):

Near as I can tell, it is a fluke that it was OK with `next_gen._generation += 1`.

The general rule appears to amount to "access private methods and data only via self."  pylint doesn't know *anything* about flow.  It doesn't care that next_gen will be a copy of a self.

You can call `self._prime_me()` and you can update `self._generation` all you want, but if you want to copy the object and access them via the copy, you're going to have to implement non-private methods and data.